# Isotope Filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Just posting here to try and grab some help! I have been playing with the (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin for well over 5 hours now and I'm just stuck.. Basically, I have two sort functions, one by name and the other by "Number" (which is labelled headliner as a button).

My question is, why if I have the numbers say for example 1- 9 individally set on each item, does it place "Wolfpack" to the right when it should be the 4th item?

Each item has `<p class="numberv">NUMBER HERE</p>` which defined the sort.

I'm using :

```
number : function( $elem ) {
    return parseInt($elem.find('.numberv').text());
    }
```

To actually sort them in the isotope function. Any help would be great.

Test Page: http://pmf.v5.cloudsvr.com.au/lineupnew

Regards,

Shannon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had you had a look at David DeSandro's demo fiddles [here](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/JcHcc/) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/DQydj/)?